# SSIS does not write to Excel

Tags: excel, ssis

I can use SSIS to write a SQL server table using OLEDB source to a flat file but when I try to write to Excel I don't get any records.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you certain the query returns records?

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS right click on project.

Select properties/debugging

Navigate to “Debugging” option from left panel and from Right panel change **Run64BitRuntime** value to false.